# Find the joint pdf of $X_{(n/2)}$ and $M$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, order-statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ be a random sample from a Uniform$(0, θ)$ population with
$θ > 0$, where $n$ is an even integer. Let $M=\frac{X_{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}+X_{\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}}{2}$ be the median of the random sample. Find the
joint pdf of $X_{(n/2)}$ and $M$.

Here I find that $$f_{X_{(n/2)}} = \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)!\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{1}{\theta}\left(1-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{n/2}.$$

But I not sure how to find the rest. Can I have some guidance?

Comment: This is not what is asked for. How do you define $M$?

Comment: So if $X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)}$ are the order statistics you're looking for the joint distribution of $X_{(n/2)}$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}X_{(n/2)} + \tfrac{1}{2}X_{(n/2+1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you can set $n=2k$, $k=1,2,3,...$

Using the Order Statistics you have that the joint density $(X_{(k)};X_{(k+1)})$ is

$$f_{X_{(k)},X_{(k+1)}}(x,y)=\frac{(2k)!}{[\theta(k-1)!]^2}\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{k-1}\cdot \left(1-\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(x;\theta)}(y)$$

Given this joint density, you are requested to calculate the joint density of

$$\left( X_{(k)}; \frac{X_{(k)}+X_{(k+1)}}{2}\right)$$

I think you can proceed by yourself using standard method of transformation to solve the problem (i.e. the jacobian method)

To use the jacobian, simply set (remember that $0<x<y<\theta$

$$\begin{cases}
z=\frac{x+y}{2} \\
u=x
\end{cases}$$

easy calculate the jacobian that is $|J|=2$ and then just substituting in the joint density you get

$$f_{UZ}(u,z)=\frac{2(2k)!}{[\theta(k-1)!]^2}\left(\frac{u}{\theta}\right)^{k-1}\cdot \left(1-\frac{2z-u}{\theta}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(?;?)}(u)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(?;?)}(z)$$

Comment: Thanks @tommik but I actually got that joint density. Where I am having problems is in using the jacobian method. I am very confused there.

Comment: @AlexisSandoval : actually in your post I do not see any joint distribution...anyway I showed you how to calculate the requested joint pdf simply changing the variables with jacobian. I left to you to calculate the joint domain. I think that before asking and asking you can mark my answer as accepted or upvoting it...this will encourage me to answer your further questions.

Comment: Don't worry I just did it.

Comment: @AlexisSandoval: good for you.